# Completeness of weighted $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

For $\infty >p>1$ consider the weighted $L^p$ spaces $(L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),\omega dx)$ where $\omega$ is some nonnegative weight. Is it true that $(L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),\omega dx)$ is complete iff $\omega$ is a Muckenhoupt weight? I would also be glad about some nice reference on this subject

Comment: $L^p(\mu)$ with respect to a complex measure $\mu$ (or real signed finite measure) means $L^p(|\mu|)$ where $|\mu|$ is the variation measure of $\mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write $(L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),\omega\,dx)$ I would guess  you mean
the space of all measurable functions $f$ such that $|f|^p\omega\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Probably more common notations are $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,\omega)$ or  $L^p_\omega(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with the norm given by
$$\|f\|_{p,\omega} = \|f\omega^{1/p}\|_{L^p}=\left(\int|f(x)|^p\omega(x)\,dx\right)^{1/p}$$

*Here are some hints:*

- What does completeness of $L^p_\omega(\mathbb{R}^n)$ mean in terms of Cauchy sequences?
- Can you rephrase that into a problem in $L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$?

Now, what do you know about [Muckenhoupt weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muckenhoupt_weights)?

Comment: I forgot to take into account that $\omega$ is bounded and nonnegative. Thanks!

Comment: @user99432 Do you really need these conditions? You might try to prove the statement without the conditions, or try to find some counterexample.